# How to access each element after a split

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, split, filereader

I am trying to read from a text file and split it into three separate categories. ID, address, and weight. However, whenever I try to access the address and weight I have an error. Does anyone see the problem?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Project1
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> packages = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> weights = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Provide the file path
    File file = new File(args[0]);

    //Reads the file
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String str;
    while((str = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(str.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            //System.out.println(str);
            //Splits the string by commas and trims whitespace
            String[] result = str.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*", 3);
            packages.add(result[0]);

            //ERROR: Doesn't know what result[1] or result[2] is.
            //addresses.add(result[1]);
            //weights.add(result[2]);

            System.out.println(result[0]);
            //System.out.println(result[1]);
            //System.out.println(result[2]);

        }   
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < packages.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(packages.get(i));
    }

}
}
```

Here is the text file (The format is intentional):

,123-ABC-4567, 15 W. 15th St.,        50.1

456-BgT-79876,    22 Broadway,       24

QAZ-456-QWER,      100 East 20th Street,     50

Q2Z-457-QWER,      200 East 20th Street, 49

678-FGH-9845 ,,     45 5th Ave,,         12.2,

678-FGH-9846,45 5th Ave,12.2

123-A BC-9999,       46 Foo Bar, 220.0

347-poy-3465,      101 B'way,24

,123-FBC-4567,      15 West 15th St., 50.1

678-FGH-8465      45 5th Ave         12.2

Comment: In some lines of a text file, there is a comma which is creating a problem.

Comment: You are splitting on `\\s*,\\s*` but in the last line `678-FGH-8465 45 5th Ave 12.2` there is no comma.

Comment: Your first and second last line has an extra comma which is creating problem. Also some lines have two `,,` commas due to which again you will have problem nad your last line doesn't seem to have any comma so multiple data problems you need to fix and also, in split method, you don't need to specify second argument and instead use a better regex to get all the values.

Comment: The text file is supposed to have multiple commas. So does anyone know a way around this to access each part?

Comment: If your data can't be changed and stays as it is, you should use a good regex that captures you data smartly.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I wrote a if statement that checks if the line contains a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the pattern in your data, where some lines start with an unneeded comma, and some lines having multiple commas as delimiter and one line not even having any comma delimiter and instead space as delimiter, you will have to use a regex that handles all these behaviors. You can use this regex which does it all for your data and captures appropriately.

```
([\w- ]+?)[ ,]+([\w .']+)[ ,]+([\d.]+)
```

Here is the explanation for above regex,

- `([\w- ]+?)` - Captures `ID` data which consists of word characters hyphen and space and places it in group1
- `[ ,]+` - This acts as a delimiter where it can be one or more space or comma
- `([\w .']+)` - This captures `address` data which consists of word characters, space and `.` and places it in group2
- `[ ,]+` - Again the delimiter as described above
- `([\d.]+)` - This captures the `weight` data which consists of numbers and `.` and places it in group3

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vUDUUF/2)**

Here is the modified Java code you can use. I've removed some of your variable declarations which you can have them back as needed. This code prints all the information after capturing the way you wanted using `Matcher` object.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w- ]+?)[ ,]+([\\w .']+)[ ,]+([\\d.]+)");

// Reads the file
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data1.txt"))) {

    String str;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Id: %s, Address: %s, Weight: %s",
                    new Object[] { m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3) }));
        }
    }
}
```

Prints,

```
Id: 456-BgT-79876, Address: 22 Broadway, Weight: 24
Id: QAZ-456-QWER, Address: 100 East 20th Street, Weight: 50
Id: Q2Z-457-QWER, Address: 200 East 20th Street, Weight: 49
Id: 678-FGH-9845, Address: 45 5th Ave, Weight: 12.2
Id: 678-FGH-9846, Address: 45 5th Ave, Weight: 12.2
Id: 123-A BC-9999, Address: 46 Foo Bar, Weight: 220.0
Id: 347-poy-3465, Address: 101 B'way, Weight: 24
Id: 678-FGH-8465, Address: 45 5th Ave, Weight: 12.2
```

Let me know if this works for you and if you have any query further.

Answer (score 0):

The last line only contains one token. So split will only return an array with one element.

A minimal reproducing example:

```
import java.io.*;

class Project1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Provide the file path
        File file = new File(args[0]);

        //Reads the file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (str.trim().length() > 0) {
                String[] result = str.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*", 3);
                System.out.println(result[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this input file:

```
678-FGH-8465 45 5th Ave 12.2
```

The output looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Project1.main(a.java:22)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So you will have to decide, what your program should do in such cases. You might ignore those lines, print an error, or only add the first token in one of your lists.

Answer (score 0):

you can add following code in your code

```
            if (result.length > 0) {
                packages.add(result[0]);
            }
            if (result.length > 1) {
                addresses.add(result[1]);
            }
            if (result.length > 2) {
                weights.add(result[2]);
            }
```